# Why does the error "string subscript out of range" is appearing while debugging the below code

Tags: c++

Here is the code.
I am getting an error "string subscript out of range" while debugging the below code. So please find
where the error is and the solution.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        s[i] = 'A';
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `s[i] = 'A';` is *changing* the character at position i, but the string is empty and there is no character at that position. What you want to do is *append* a new character to the string like this `s += 'A';` or `s.push_back('A');`.

Comment: Or, initialize the size of the `string` beforehand, `string s(51, '\0');` or `string s; s.resize(51);`, then the original loop will work.